# concat: how to handle each subscribe with a specific next function as independent

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'd like to handle the response of each subscribe independently in a concat observable. I'm using Rxjs 5 in angular2.

```
let source1 = //some Http service
let source2 = //some Http service
let source3 = //some Http service  

Observable.concat(source1,source2,source3)
      .subscribe(data=> console.log(data));
```

The above concat observable works fine, as long as the data returned from each source is of the same type and I have to handle the returned data in the same way for all 3 sources.

But what if the sources where generating a promise from a different service and each source's data returned in the subscription was different and needed to be handled uniquely. Is this possible? The following is a pseudo code of what I'm asking for.

```
let source1 = //some Http service1 returns a string
let source2 = //some Http service2 returns a number
let source3 = //some Http service3 returns a boolean  

//The following is pseudo code
Observable.concat(source1,source2,source3)
      .subscribe(data_source1=> console.log(data_source1))
      .subscribe(data_source2=> console.log(data_source2 +3))
      .subscribe(data_source3=> console.log(data_source3 === true));
```

p.s. Clearly all the responses need to be handled sequentially not in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`forkJoin()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) that emits after all Observables complete.

However, you say you want to handle responses sequentially so I guess you want to start requests one after another.

This is still solvable with `concat` and then merging all responses into a single array with `toArray()`.

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

let source1 = Observable.of(42).do(() => console.log('source1')).delay(500);
let source2 = Observable.of(true).do(() => console.log('source2')).delay(500);
let source3 = Observable.of("Hello, World!").do(() => console.log('source3')).delay(500);

Observable.concat(source1, source2, source3)
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

This prints to console:

```
"source1"
"source2"
"source3"
[42, true, "Hello, World!"]
```

There're multiple `do()` operators to show that the Observables are started with delay.

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/kikuceh/1/edit